# Vlookup range in multiple column

Tags: vlookup, range

How can I apply the `VLOOKUP` function when lookup ranges and value in multiple column.

Data and result same but table range different. I need two different formula based on the following data and table.

```
REQUIRED-I                              REQUIRED-II             
DATA-I          TABLE-1                 DATA-II         TABLE-II    
PART    RESULT      PART    STATUS  PART    STATUS      PART    RESULT      US  UK
2644            2625    US  2683    UK      2644            2625    2683
2693    UK      2633    US  2667    UK      2693    UK      2633    2667
2691    UK      2654    US  2668    UK      2691    UK      2654    2668
2668    UK      2610    US  2685    UK      2668    UK      2610    2685
2667    UK      2653    US  2675    UK      2667    UK      2653    2675
2685    UK      2658    US  2599    UK      2685    UK      2658    2599
2675    UK      2637    US  2691    UK      2675    UK      2637    2691
2460    UK      2652    US  2693    UK      2460    UK      2652    2693
2610    US              2460    UK      2610    US          2460
2697                    2688    UK      2697                2688
2688    UK                          2688    UK          
2599    UK                          2599    UK          
2626                                2626                
2597                                2597                
2637    US                          2637    US          
2652    US                          2652    US          
2654    US                          2654    US          
2683    UK                          2683    UK          
2653    US                          2653    US          
2664                                2664                
2633    US                          2633    US          
2558                                2558
```

Visually:
[image]

Comment: (1) Please fix your data so they match the image.  (2) You have presented us with a list of digraphs and four-digit numbers, leaving us to look for a pattern and try to read your mind.  Lots of people would be happy to help you, but we’re not so happy to have to work hard just to understand the question.  ***EXPLAIN*** which cells have raw data, which cells (need to) have a formula, and what you want the formula to do. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For vlookup, the lookup range must be a contiguous, single range - it cannot be split or on different multiple columns.

As for the data you show it would be better to show images of the sheet and how the data is laid out.

Edit:
Had to build your data, so see the image, only did the first table. Note that the part status table for the US and UK has been combined into 1 table. You can split it out by having two vlookups, but it is simpler to just have 1 table IMHO and you can keep it sorted to see which is which.

Note the use of named ranges...

This is the formula in B4 :

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,Part_Status,2,0),$E$2)
```

and the iferror will put the word "check" in the result if there is no value, "check" is in cell E2 and you can edit it...

[image]

Comment: thank for you reply.                                                                                    I need a formula B4 from the table 1 (DATA RANGE D4:G13) and need a another formula J4 from the table 2 (DATA RANGE L3:M13)                if A4(2644) matched from the table 1 (DATA RANGE D4:G13) return the text in column B4 this is my first requirement and another requirements is if match I4(2644) from the table 2 return the value in column J4.

Comment: Please help someone it's really appreciated

Comment: In vlookup, A4 is the item being looked for in the first column in the data range, Part_Status is the data range where the result will come from - actually column 2 and the 0 is to get an exact result . Excel has more info in the help about it.