# Automatic Serial number in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, serial-number

Column A(A3:A24) and B(B3:B24) contain unique number and text. If column B is blank, I want column C to contain a number that counts down to 1 in the last row that contains a blank cell in column B.

The following picture shows what the worksheet should look like, except that C3 should contain a 6.

[image]

Comment: I can't see what formula would produce your illustration: why is there no entry in `C1`?

Comment: Is this a duplicate post? You seem to have the same source data as this question : https://superuser.com/questions/1255232/vlookup-range-in-multiple-column/1255234?noredirect=1#comment1845446_1255234

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Starting the data range row 2 that's reason C1 is blanks.

Comment: maybe same data but different requirements.

Comment: You have two identities....?

Comment: You should be able to make use of the techniques shown in the other post...

Comment: @PETER - Sorry, I meant why is there no entry in `C3`? In any case you should look at the `COUNTBLANK()` function.

Comment: Today I saw the post its little bit similar my data that's why I used the same data. Apology for the mistake.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to type in C3. In column C3 serial number is 6.

Comment: how to apply countblank() function reverse order wise please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following formula to count the number of blank cells in the column B from the current row to the end of the range.

```
=IF(B3="",COUNTIF(B3:B$24,""),"")
```

If column B contain is a blank cell, the formula will count the number of blank cells from this row to the end of the range.